# Images in Hugo Academic theme blank widget not displaying

Tags: hugo

I am trying to create a blank widget in the Hugo Academic theme to display some images of my art work. I would like two columns, so that two images are displayed within the blank widget. I have the following code below. Note that I have made the widget active and updated the menu to display the widget... which it does. However, the images are not displayed. Any help is appreciated!

```
+++
# Blank widget.
widget = "blank" 
headless = true  
active = true  
weight = 25  

title = "Art Work"

[design]

columns = "2"

[[item]]
  title = ""
  content = ""
  align = "left"  # Choose `center`, `left`, or `right`.

  overlay_img = "static/img/AMELIORATE.jpeg"  

[[item]]
  title = ""
  content = ""
  align = "right"

  overlay_img = "static/img/THROUGH.jpeg"  # Image path relative to your `static/img/` folder.

[[item]]
  title = ""
  content = ""
  align = "left"

  overlay_img = "static/img/USE ME UP.jpeg"  # Image path relative to your `static/img/` folder.

[[item]]
  title = ""
  content = ""
  align = "right"

  overlay_img = "static/img/VENOM.jpeg"  # Image path relative to your `static/img/` folder.

 [[item]]
  title = ""
  content = ""
  align = "left"

  overlay_img = "static/img/CHAOS.jpeg"  # Image path relative to your `static/img/` folder.

 [[item]]
  title = ""
  content = ""
  align = "right"

  overlay_img = "static/img/ROSE.jpeg"  # Image path relative to your `static/img/` folder.

+++
```